# What are the differences between CGRect options?

Tags: swift, int, double, cgrect, cgfloat

Typically when creating a frame for a view I use CGRect where the parameters accepts CGFloat, Double or Int. They all create a rectangle with coordinates and dimensions specified as a CGFloat, Int or Double (summarized from Apple Doc), but does it matter which type of value you choose to use? Is there some underlying difference in choosing one option over the other. Is it the way they use memory differently?

Comment: That will depend on your needs. They are convenience initialisers. Int and Double are preferred.

Comment: It's basically handling the dirty work so you don't have to convert them to a single type before hand.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any difference.

Those are convenience initializers. That means you can have *inits* with different parameters/parameter types.

But, of course, if you want to create a `CGRect` with edges that are not `Int` (if you want real numbers), than you will need to use the `init` with `Double` or `CGFloat` parameters (even though the syntax will look pretty much the same, behind the scenes, the initializer for that specific type will be called).